# How do I make only one partition and that partition root mounted into multiple partitions?

Tags: linux, lvm

I use Pubic Cloud server with Linux OS. I want to create another partition. What should I do?
I want to use LVM, but Linux said

```
Can't open /dev/vda1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

as well as

```
pvcreate /dev/vda1
```

Let's see:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/vda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000aea28

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048    83875364    41936658+  8e  Linux LVM

# pvcreate /dev/vda1
Can't open /dev/vda1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
Can't open /dev/vda1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

Please help me. I'm still a newbie.

Comment: you will have to add another drive /dev/vdb and then you can use fdiak and LVM tools to bring it into a volume. Learn fdisk and LVM before you use on your critical data.

Comment: I don't get your title: You say you want only one partition, and then go on to ask about creating another partition.